# Apply same CSS to multiple class in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

There are 3 classes with the same CSS

```
const useStyles=makeStyles((theme)=>({
 classA:{color:'green'},
classB:{color:'green'},
classC:{color:'green'}
})
```

How to use it as in CSS
for example

`ClassA ClassB ClassC:{color:'green'}`

Comment: i have a way to get your answer but it wont use material UI.. is that ok?

Comment: Instead of using this you can go for other ways like CSS modules, here's doc where they have specified that Mui support for other methods: https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#react-jss

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understood your question, but you can do something like this:

```
    const useStyles=makeStyles((theme)=>({
     const generalColor: {color: 'green'};
     return {
      generalColor,
      classA:{...generalColor, other attributes},
      classB:{...generalColor, other attributes},
      classC:{...generalColor, other attributes}
           }
    })
```

That way, if an attribute or more are the same for your classes, you can declare it one time in a `const`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please help me more?
I am unable to do it your way.

I have code as
`classA:{ "& button":{margin:10},"& th:{color:blue}}, classB::{ "& button":{margin:10},"& th:{color:blue}}  }` . Rather than using same block of code multiple time, i woild like to simplify it.

Comment: So if you are using CSS you can simply write a class where you have the general styling like: `generalClass:{ "& button":{margin:10},"& th:{color:blue}}`, and your other classes normal like `classA: {font-size: 16px}` (hope you got the idea) and call them all where you need it like `<button class="generalClass classA"></button> @Rujal